# Handle subprocesses in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to run a subprocess, execute some code, and then kill the started process; I don't need the output of this subprocess. I tried something like this:

```
def start
  @@rtorrentIO ||= IO.popen("rtorrent")
  sleep 0.5
end
def stop
  Process.kill(9, @@rtorrentIO.pid) if defined? @@rtorrentIO
  @@rtorrentIO = nil
end

start
sleep 0.5
#some code there
stop
```

but the terminal doesn't react to any actions that I did (even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> escape). What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I was a little mistake in the initial conditions. In fact terminal react for all my actions but I don't see any symbols that I write before command executes. In the picture below I consistently execute the following commands: mangaParser.rb; whoami; ps;
And that was I get to output:
[image]

However, if i try to break runned command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> escape, it was failure (e.g. I can't break the following sequence of command without other terminal: mangaParser.rb; ping google.com;)

Comment: What do you get when you print `@@torrentIO.pid` before doing `Process.kill`?

Comment: @7stud Fixnum that represent process id of rtorrent, obviously :) I check it few times - it's really process id of runned subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def start
  @rtorrentIO ||= IO.popen("rtorrent",'w') #default mode is 'r'
  sleep 0.5
end
def stop
  Process.kill(9, @rtorrentIO.pid) if defined? @rtorrentIO
  @rtorrentIO = nil
end

start


sleep 0.5
#some code there
stop
```

to make it into a self-contained example, it works fine for me. You should probably open the pipe for writing `(..,"w")`, since you're uninterested in the output (and if you're not interested in writing into it, then there's no point in opening the process with `popen` and you're better off using things like `pid = Process.spawn('rtorrent')`).

**UPDATE**
The problem you're experiencing is due to `rtorrent` messing up your terminal by writing special terminal control sequences (intentionally or not) to its output. This'll happen from time to time (`cat`ting a random binary file will very likely mess up your terminal as you'll likely encounter a byte sequence that's somehow special to the terminal). The solution is to run `reset` in the terminal (see `man reset` for more details)--you'll have to type it in blindly.

If you don't want `rtorrent` to do that, redirecting its *stdout* and *stderr* (these are normally bound to your terminal) will most likely stop it from writing to your terminal.  Apart from that, you could do `system reset` in the `stop` method to fix what `rtorrent` has done.

Below is a combination of the above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def start
  @pid ||= Process.spawn "rtorrent" #, err: '/dev/null', out: '/dev/null'
  sleep 0.5
end
def stop
  Process.kill(9, @pid) if @pid
  @pid = nil
  system 'reset'
end

start


sleep 0.5
#some code there
stop
```

Comment: OK, then using popen was not good idea. I'm reaaly don't interested in reading or writing to that process. I tried to use `fork{exec('rtorrent')}` instead of popen, but result was same

Comment: I updated my answer to correspond to your UPDATE. Note: `Process.spawn` is essential fork{ exec('...') } as far as I know.